# The IDCODE read from the device does not match the IDCODE in the BSDL file

Tags: programmable-logic

I checked many different posts with the same problem, but none of the advises were helpful thus far. So, I am using ISE 14.7, DLC9G USB Cable, and trying to program the XPLA3 256 CPLD. After successful generation of programming file I click on the 'Configure Target Device' in the processes window and this lunches the IMPACT. **The CPLD is directly connected to the programming cable pin-to-pin with no extra peripheral components.**

[image]

Then I click on **Boundary Scan** and then right click **Add Xlilnx Device** and choose the **.jed** file from the project folder.

[image]

Looks like the device is added successfully. Now, when I right click -> **Program on the device**, I get a properties window and press OK:

[image]

but programming fails. Here's the console output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
GUI --- Auto connect to cable...
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Plugin Version: 2.4.4
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: no JTAG device was found.
AutoDetecting cable. Please wait.
*** WARNING ***: When port is set to auto detect mode, cable speed is set to default 6 MHz regardless of explicit arguments supplied for setting the baud rates
PROGRESS_START - Starting Operation.
Connecting to cable (Usb Port - USB21).
Checking cable driver.
Driver file xusbdfwu.sys found.
Driver version: src=1027, dest=1027.
Driver windrvr6.sys version = 11.3.0.0. WinDriver v11.30 Jungo Connectivity (c) 1997 - 2013 Build Date: May 12 2013 x86_64 64bit SYS 14:54:36, version = 1130.
Cable PID = 0008.
Max current requested during enumeration is 74 mA.
Type = 0x0004.
Cable Type = 3, Revision = 0.
Setting cable speed to 6 MHz.
Cable connection established.
Firmware version = 1303.
File version of C:/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/data/xusb_xlp.hex = 1303.
Firmware hex file version = 1303.
PLD file version = 0012h.
PLD version = 0012h.
PROGRESS_END - End Operation.
Elapsed time =      1 sec.
Type = 0x0004.
ESN option: 000016D4573401.
INFO:iMPACT - Current time: 5/29/2014 5:22:52 PM
PROGRESS_START - Starting Operation.
INFO:iMPACT:583 - '1': The idcode read from the device does not match the idcode in the bsdl File.
INFO:iMPACT:1578 - '1':  Device IDCODE :        00001111111111111000000000000001
INFO:iMPACT:1579 - '1': Expected IDCODE:    00000100100101001000000000000001
PROGRESS_END - End Operation.
Elapsed time =      0 sec.
```

Then I tried **Debug -> Chain Integrity Test**, but it fails too:

```
INFO:iMPACT - Current time: 5/29/2014 5:26:04 PM
Maximum TCK operating frequency for this device chain: 10000000.
Validating chain...
INFO:iMPACT:1209 - Testing for '0' at position 9.The Instruction capture of the device 1 does not match expected capture.
INFO:iMPACT:1206 - Instruction Capture = '11111111111'
INFO:iMPACT:1207 - Expected    Capture = '10101000001'
INFO:iMPACT:2130 - Boundary-scan chain test failed . Please check tdi->tdo connection between  device:'1' ( 'xcr3256xl') and the cable .
    A problem may exist in the hardware configuration.
    Check that the cable, scan chain, and power connections are intact,
    that the specified scan chain configuration matches the actual hardware, and
    that the power supply is adequate and delivering the correct voltage.
```

So I checked the connections all over again and everything looks intact.
I also checked the BSDL file for this device and in contains the following:

```
...
attribute INSTRUCTION_CAPTURE of XCR3256XL_TQ144 : entity is "00001" ;
attribute IDCODE_REGISTER of XCR3256XL_TQ144 : entity is "XXXX0100100101001011000010010011";
attribute REGISTER_ACCESS of XCR3256XL_TQ144 : entity is
...
```

I tried to mask the "Manufacturing section" with 'X's, but it did not help. Please, any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be any number of things.  Assuming you've checked (double checked, triple checked, etc) that your JTAG connections are correct, I'd try the following additively, one at a time, in this order:

1. Insert a small resistor (between 22R and 220R) in the TDI line, as close as possible to the CPLD.
2. Snubber circuit - 68R and 100pF in series to GND on the TCK line, as close as possible to the CPLD.
3. Another resistor, same size as the TDI one, but on the TMS line as close as possible to the CPLD.
4. Another resistor, same size as the TDI one, but on the TDO line as close as possible to the connector.

[edit] scratch the clock impedance matching, I was thinking of the FPGA CCLK signal, which is 50 ohm. [/edit]

1,3,4 damp reflections on the data in and out.  2 tries to damp ringing on the TCK line.

I suspect a combination of 1 & 2 will solve your problem.

Comment: Did not help ((. Just to clarify, I used 1,3,4 in series, and the 2 was TCK-resistor-capacitor-GND.

Comment: Hmmm time to eliminate other variables.  Your screendump shows that the JTAG programmer is being identified OK by iMPACT, so that's not the problem. Do you have another JTAG part or board that you can test the programmer and connections against?  Are you running the JTAG programmer off your board's Vcc, or an internal voltage?

Comment: It could be the programmer or the actual cpld. I returned the programmer and ordered a different one. Will see how it will do. I also ordered another CPLD. It's possible that something was damaged during soldering it to PCB.

Comment: I got a new programmer - Digilent HS2. It was $20 more expensive, but I managed to program my CPLD within seconds upon opening the box. Later I will check the old CPLD to see if it was a problem.

Comment: I think the programmer driver was not properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

as my experience, if Vref in jtag is low, this problem occurs.
in my AVA6S03 board, Vref must be greater than 7.0 volt.